# How to implement the retry on timeout in Camel?

Tags: timeout, apache-camel

How should I implement a Camel route to achieve the following?

1. Call an external service by putting the request to a JMS broker
2. Wait for its response ***on another thread***, thus the original thread is not blocked
3. ***if request timeout, starts from step 2 again (this part could be done by polling)***; else continue
4. Process the response

***My Test Route Implementation***

```
// Simulate receiving message from upstream
from("direct:jmsStart")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
        .validate(new TestValidator("Some basic validation"))
        .to("seda:sell");

// Sell Flow Starts
from("seda:sell")
        .transform(new TestTransformer("Convert to internal data structure"))
        .validate(new TestValidator("ValidateSellStatus"))
        .process(new TestProcessor("Prepare request to external system"))
        .process(new TestProcessor("Persist the request to DB")) // <== Any better persistence suggestion??
        .to("seda:jmsRequestToExternal");

// Simulate External System Processing
from("seda:jmsRequestToExternal")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "External System Processing...")
        .delay(1000).to("seda:jmsReplyFromExternal");

// External System response received
from("seda:jmsReplyFromExternal")
        .process(new TestProcessor("Mark Complete"))
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "Send reply to upstream");

// Trigger retry - resend those requests without a response
from("timer://poller?period=30000")
        .process(new TestProcessor("Get pending requests from DB"))  // <== Any better persistence suggestion??
        .to("seda:jmsRequestToExternal");
```

To achieve low latency, all of the route/sub-route should not block each other. Would like to understand if there is any better implementation can achieve the same? To my understanding, the redeliver mechanism on Camel seems to be relies on blocking timeout or exception mechanism which may not suit low latency application.

Comment: Do you mean start from step 1? Otherwise you are just waiting forever.

Comment: If the JMS queue is being read and a web service called with the queues message you should be able to configure the queue to retry as described in this document.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1209configuringfailedmessageredelive01.html

Answer (score 18):

You need to use an exception handler with a re-delivery policy also know as the `RedeliveryErrorHandler` in Camel. This error handler will allow you to set the number of retries for example and also set things like the delay between reties etc.

The following properties are available for the `RedeliveryErrorHandler`

- MaximumRedeliveries: Maximum number of redelivery attempts allowed. 0 is used to disable redelivery,and -1 will attempt redelivery forever untilit succeeds.
- RedeliveryDelay: Fixed delay in milliseconds between each redelivery attempt.
- MaximumRedeliveryDelay: An upper bound in milliseconds for redelivery delay. This is used when you specify nonfixeddelays, such as exponential backoff, to avoid the delay growing too large.Using error handlers with redelivery
- AsyncDelayedRedelivery: Dictates whether or not Camel should use asynchronous delayed redelivery. When a redelivery is scheduled to be redelivered in the future, Camel would normally have to block the current thread until it’s time for redelivery. By enabling this option, you let Camel use a scheduler so that an asynchronous thread will perform the redelivery. This ensures that no thread is blocked while waiting for redelivery.
- BackOffMultiplier: Exponential backoff multiplier used to multiply each consequent delay.RedeliveryDelay is the starting delay.Exponential backoff is disabled by default.
- CollisionAvoidanceFactor: A percentage to use when calculating a random delay offset (to avoid using the same delay at the next attempt). Will start with the RedeliveryDelay as the starting delay.Collision avoidance is disabled by default.
- DelayPattern: A pattern to use for calculating the delay. Thepattern allows you to specify fixed delays forinterval groups.For example, the pattern "0:1000;5:5000;10:30000" will use a 1 second delay for attempts 0 to 4, 5 seconds for attempts 5 to 9, and 30 seconds for subsequent attempts.
- RetryAttemptedLogLevel: Log level used when a redelivery attempt is performed.
- RetriesExhaustedLogLevel: Log level used when all redelivery attempts have failed.
- LogStackTrace boolean true Specifies whether or not stacktraces should be logged when all redelivery attempts have failed.
- LogRetryStackTrace:Specifies whether or not stacktraces should be logged when a delivery has failed.
- LogRetryAttempted: Specifies whether or not redelivery attempts should be logged.
- LogExhausted: Specifies whether or not the exhaustion of redelivery attempts (when all redelivery
  attempts have failed) should be logged.
- LogHandled: Specifies whether or not handled exceptions should be logged.

Using this in Java is simple you can use the following code:

```
errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
.maximumRedeliveries(3) 
.backOffMultiplier(4)
.retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));
```

Or if you want in Spring XML DSL:

```
<errorHandler id="myErrorHandler" type="DefaultErrorHandler"
    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="5"
       retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"
       backOffMultiplier="2"
       useExponentialBackOff="true"/>
</errorHandler>
```

You can use this to retry the web-service call a set number of time and then throw an exception if you cannot connect say after 5 retry attempts.

Comment: What if the timeout won't throw an  exception, as the external service is invoked asynchronously with jms(i.e. nonblocking).

Comment: Could you provide more details in the question then? Seems like there is a lot of things I am not aware of.

Comment: Note that `MaximumRedeliveryDelay` is actually the delay between each retry, and `RedeliveryDelay` is the initial delay before first retry. The javadoc is right but var name is confusing.

Comment: The question is 8 years old so something might have changed.